# Pygame code reduction when using many buttons in a window

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, python-3.7

```
elif 192 < mouseY < 224:
    draw = "default"
    if iconSelected == "watertower":
        iconSelected = None
    else:
        iconSelected = "watertower"
```

So I am using pygame, and I have lots and lots of buttons, how do I reduce this code, because it's very repetition but I'm not sure how to reduce it. All the "Elif " look like this, but I basically need a toggle.
-Thanks

Comment: It gets set to None, the variable, which basically means nothing is selected

Comment: Could you show some more of your code and explain a bit more? I'm sure adding an abstraction for your buttons would reduce code duplication and improve readability.

Comment: @Skezza if you want a code review post your complete progam on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. You don't need to create another account there. Make sure that your program is runnable and works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense the 4 lines to 1:

```
iconSelected = "watertower" if iconSelected != "watertower" else None
```

Or, depending on context, the other way around may be clearer:

```
iconSelected = None if iconSelected == "watertower" else "watertower"
```

Comment: Would iconSelected = "watertower" if iconSelected != "watertower" else iconSelected = None work?

Comment: @Skezza No, it would not. The way I showed is shorter and works.